Gateway [SCR] Error while trying to bind reference - APIM-4.2.0
I'm following the steps given in WSO2 GIT Repo here. Did the all the configs as instructed. Placed the jar in lib folder and confirmed its reflected in dropins too when the server starts. Am I missing anything here?
use below versions to build the jar:
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
          <!--org.wso2.carbon.apimgt component version-->
        <carbon.apimgt.version>9.29.120</carbon.apimgt.version>
          <!--synapse-core version-->
        <synapse.version>4.0.0-wso2v105</synapse.version>
    </properties>

Error logs when the server starts:
[2024-08-18 13:51:38,425]  INFO - CustomDataProvider Successfully initialized
[2024-08-18 13:51:38,438] DEBUG - EventHubClient [{ Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 500bb4bc-034e-46df-8e0a-ec459bb7e872 }] - Creating Eventhub client instance.
[2024-08-18 13:51:38,450] ERROR - gateway [SCR] Error while trying to bind reference Reference[name = api.manager.config.service, interface = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIManagerConfigurationService, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setAPIManagerConfigurationService, unbind = unsetAPIManagerConfigurationService]
    Details:
    Problematic reference = Reference[name = api.manager.config.service, interface = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIManagerConfigurationService, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setAPIManagerConfigurationService, unbind = unsetAPIManagerConfigurationService]
    of service component = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.handlers
    component implementation class = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.internal.APIHandlerServiceComponent
    located in bundle with symbolic name = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway
    bundle location = reference:file:../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.28.116.77.jar
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bind(ServiceComponentProp.java:218) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:343) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.internal.SequenceEditorServiceComponent.activate(SequenceEditorServiceComponent.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:213) ~[org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.175.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence.service.InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.activate(InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.java:50) ~[org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence_4.7.175.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name
    at feign.Util.checkNotNull(Util.java:123) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.Target$HardCodedTarget.<init>(Target.java:78) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.Target$HardCodedTarget.<init>(Target.java:73) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:201) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.auth.AuthClient.getSASToken(AuthClient.java:58) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client.EventHubProducerClientFactory.getSASToken(EventHubProducerClientFactory.java:95) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client.EventHubProducerClientFactory.create(EventHubProducerClientFactory.java:55) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client.EventHubClient.createProducerWithRetry(EventHubClient.java:108) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client.EventHubClient.<init>(EventHubClient.java:86) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.cloud.DefaultAnalyticsMetricReporter.<init>(DefaultAnalyticsMetricReporter.java:63) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.MetricReporterFactory.createMetricReporter(MetricReporterFactory.java:52) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics.publishers.impl.AnalyticsDataPublisher.initialize(AnalyticsDataPublisher.java:120) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics_9.28.116.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics.AnalyticsServiceReferenceHolder.setConfigurations(AnalyticsServiceReferenceHolder.java:46) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics_9.28.116.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.internal.APIHandlerServiceComponent.setAPIManagerConfigurationService_aroundBody12(APIHandlerServiceComponent.java:258) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.internal.APIHandlerServiceComponent.setAPIManagerConfigurationService(APIHandlerServiceComponent.java:1) ~[?:?]
    ... 94 more


Try changing the <carbon.apimgt.version> to 9.28.116
